# TUSB106 To DP Port and USB

Tags: usb, displayport

I have a SOM which is having USB Type C + DP , Now I need to develop a carrier Board for the following requirement as given in Block diagram.

[image]

Is TUSB1064 Will capable of doing that, as mentioned in block diagram.
Requirements:
Both Ports Should work concurrently.